# Python: appending list element that is already in the list

Tags: python, list

I want to go from `list1 = [[x]]` to `list2 = [[x],[x,2]]`. The second element of `list2` should be created from the first element. I tried this:

```
list1 = [[1]]
list1.append(list1[0])
list1[1].append(2)
list2 = list1
```

But this results in:

```
list2=[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

and not what I actually wanted:

```
list2=[[1], [1, 2]]
```

as I wanted.

I guess that this is because when I append `list1[0]`, this is not a copy of `list1[0]`, but index 1 of `list1` is still pointing to the same object.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this python 2 or 3? You'll have to actually copy the list, otherwise you're just appending a reference.

Python 2:

```
list1 = [[1]]
list1.append(list(list1[0]))
list1[1].append(2)
```

Or list.copy was explicitly added in version 3.3:

```
list1 = [[1]]
list1.append(list1[0].copy())
list1[1].append(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `list1.append(list1[0])` line appends an alias of the 0-th element, which is a list object, of `list1` to itself. Now `list1` looks like this in memory:

```
   [1] <-----+
    ^        |
    |        |
[index 0, index 1]
```

That is, there are two references to the same inner list at both index 0 and 1.

Then, `list1[1].append(2)` pushes 2 to this single list, making it:

```
   [1,2] <---+
    ^        |
    |        |
[index 0, index 1]
```

Finally, you add another reference to this whole structure: `list2 = list1`.

The result looks like:

```
         [1,2] <---+
          ^        |
          |        |
list1: [index 0, index 1] 
  ^ 
  |
list2
```

You've only created a total of one inner list and one outer list. Modifications done to `list2` will affect `list1`, and modifications on either index of either reference list will affect both indexes of both references.

While the example you've provided is a bit contrived and the use case is unclear (you may not actually want to copy these lists, especially if they are complex objects, and it's not clear whether it's indended that `list2` alias `list1`), you probably want something like:

```
list1 = [[1]]
list1.append(list1[0][:]) # copy using slice syntax
list1[1].append(2)
list2 = [x[:] for x in list1] # copy again using slice syntax and a list
                              # comprehension, assuming you don't want an alias
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1]]
list1.append(list1[0].copy())
list1[1].append(2)
list2 = list1
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
>>> lis=[[1]]
>>> lis
[[1]]
>>> lis.append([lis[0][0],2])
>>> lis
[[1], [1, 2]]
```